# Transform two es6 modules into one file with babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-cli

I have files `a.js` and `main.js`:

a.js:

```
export default A = 7;
```

main.js:

```
import A from './a'
console.log(A);
```

---

I want somehow process that files to get **one** result file (let say `result.js`), which I can add into html page (via `<script src="result.js"></script>`), so that when I load this html page in browser, I see `7` in console. There should be no `require()` or `import ... from ...` directives in `result.js`.

---

I try compile file main.js with babel:

```
babel main.js --presets env --out-file result.js
```

But this gives me file `result.js` with `require()` directive and without code from `a.js`:

```
'use strict';
var _a = require('./a');
var _a2 = _interopRequireDefault(_a);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
console.log(_a2.default);
```

Also I try to compile both files `a.js` and `main.js` with babel:

```
babel a.js main.js --presets env --out-file result.js
```

This gives me file `result.js` with code from `a.js` but also with `require()` directive:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = A = 7;
'use strict';
var _a = require('./a');
var _a2 = _interopRequireDefault(_a);
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
console.log(_a2.default);
```

---

How can I process that files correctly to get `result.js` without `require()` or `import ... from ...` directives?

Comment: I don’t know if there’s a built-in Babel way. (It doesn’t look like it, but things change quickly.) Some things you can do, however, are: a) run it through Rollup first, then Babel; b) use Webpack with Babel preprocessing; c) use Browserify with babel preprocessing ([Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)); d) use Webpack/Browserify after Babel.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks, seems that i can use just Webpack for this